# Customizing WP theme - how to change link for nav button in CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I've been customizing a one-page-design wordpress template (see http://ggc.inductiveplay.com) - it pulls up a floating button on the home page that :should: scroll down to the next section (#menu), but for some reason it keeps pointing to the 3rd section (#location).

I'd like to just override the link in CSS where I'm customizing the button size/appearance and assume I just have bad syntax here:

```
.a-btn {
    padding: 2px 12px !important;
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
    opacity: .8;
    z-index: 1;
    href="#menu";

}
```

If there's a quick fix for this I'd love to know, otherwise I'd love any insights on where the link is being set/computed on the site.

Comment: You can't use css to overwrite html attributes! You should look the html (php file) and change it there if is static or in the back end if it's dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can add things before and after a HTML element in css. But you can't change a link using CSS.
The below is bad CSS syntax:

```
href="#menu";
```

To add things before something in CSS you can have a HTML element like:

```
<div class="sample-text"></div>
```

Then using the following CSS:

```
.sample-text:before {
content:"blah blah";
}
```

Instead of "blah blah" you can have something else.

You can't use HTML in the CSS so you can't do what you want, but this is the closest you can get to it.

However you can change links using javascript.

Also you can only use `z-index` if you specify a `position:relative`, `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`.